# Android listview inside viewpager not swiping

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a listview inside of a viewpager. I set an empty view on the listview. If this listview starts empty, when i add something to it then right or left swipes on the listview won't switch between tabs. If the listview starts with something (not empty) when i set the adapter on it, then i can swipe. If i remove the setEmptyView on the listview, it always works whether it starts with data or without it.

How can i set an empty view and still get the listview to swipe between tabs?

This is how i set the empty view:

```
mListview.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_view));
```

the empty view is a textview directly below the listview in a linearlayout

the empty view xml:
empty_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/empty_list"
    android:textColor="@color/lighter_gray"        
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/no_item"
    android:textStyle="italic">  

</TextView>
```

Comment: To me it looks like your empty view is consuming touch

Comment: actually when the listview is empty and the empty view is displayed the swipe works. its only when i add an item to the listview that the swipe stops working

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing your empty view from the current layout file, and move it into its own dedicated layout file. Then inflate this new layout in your class when you want to use it as an empty view. The end result would be something like this (not compiled, coding from memory):

```
final View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.empty_view, null); 
mListview.setEmptyView(v);
```

or maybe

```
final View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.empty_view, mListview, false); 
mListview.setEmptyView(v);
```

Comment: when i do this then the empty view is not displayed at all when the listview is empty for some reason

Comment: With both variations?

Comment: Hmm, looks ok to me. I'm out of ideas for now, but I'll leave the answer up for others to reference.